# How to remove records from mysql table, but skip records that have constraints errors?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I try to remove records, but getting constraint error and query stops. Or I use 'delete ignore ...' but query stops too, only with warning. I can't set constraint check off, I just need remove records without constraints. Maybe mysql have some commands for this? I found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can imagine is to write a query that returns rows from you master table which don't have details, and then join result of this query with master table , something like

```
DELETE FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT pk_column FROM table1 t1
   LEFT JOIN details1 d1 ON (d1.fk_column = t1.pk_column)
   // other LEFT JOIN[s] if you have more detail tables.
   WHERE d1.pk_column IS NULL
)a ON t.pk_column = a.pk_column
```

An alternative to join, which works pretty much the same is to add `WHERE NOT EXIST` to check

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems like no other way, except joining or outer handlers (scripting languages). In my special case join is unacceptable because of 1.5M records in table, to much time to wait, so i use outer handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Add "on delete cascade" to the table/ constraint definition.

Comment: He doesn't want to remove the records that break foreign constraint, just skip them